# Nonlinear Second Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation:

$\displaystyle r''-\frac{2r'^2}{r}-r=0$

I know that the solution is of the form:

$\displaystyle r(\theta)=c_2\sec(c_1+\theta)$

... but only because I used WolframAlpha......

I am not really sure how else to solve this.  Any hints, or explicit solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: The substitution $u=r'$ gives $r''={du\over d\theta}={du\over dr}{dr\over d\theta}=u{du\over dr}$. Your equation then becomes $u{du\over dr}-{2u^2\over r}-r=0 $, or ${du\over dr}-{2\over r}u={r\over u}$. This is a [Bernoulli equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation). The substitution $q=u^{2}$ will reduce it to a linear equation.

Answer (score 2):

You must have done something wrong.  That is not a solution of this differential equation.

Comment: Thanks!  Typo... that should be squared

Comment: OK, now it's right.